# How to replace multiple \r\n in a RichTextBox document with Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried dismally. I have paragraphs consisting of Runs in a RichTextBox. Each run consists of a string with none, one, or many embeded "\r\n". I need to remove all but the first "\r\n" when there are more then one together and replace the remaining "\r\n" with "| ". The Document will have many such paragraphs.

That is, given this string:

> This \r\n is a \r\n\r\n Test. Or, \r\n\r\n\r\n this \r\n.

I need this string:

> This | is a | Test. Or, | this | .

How can this be done using Regex (C# .Net 4.5)?

TIA
(I've studied similar questions, but can't seem to get it right :()

Edit:
Thanks to all who helped. For anyone coming here, in my case the correct answer is actually a combination of the answers I received. That is, both of these
work correctly in my case.

```
    Regex.Replace(s, "(\r\n)+", "| ")   
    Regex.Replace(s, @"(\r\n)+","| ")
```

Comment: `string output = Regex.Replace("This \r\n is a \r\n\r\n Test. Or, \r\n\r\n\r\n this \r\n", "\\\\r\\\\n", "|");`   should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
string s = @"This \r\n is a \r\n\r\n Test. Or, \r\n\r\n\r\n this \r\n.";

string n = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\\r\\n)+", "|");

Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Output:

> This | is a | Test. Or, | this |.

the `+` sign at the end of the pattern means 1 or more occurrences of the previous characters. This way it will also capture multiple `\r\n\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have pairs of CF/LF chars, not `\` + `r` + `\` + `n`.

If this is the case, you should not use here *verbatim strings*
(with `@` before the actual string).

Writing `@"xx\r\n"` causes that such a string contains:

- 2 *x* chars,
- a backslash and `r`,
- a backslash and `n`.

The same for regex.

If you don't believe, run the following code:

```
string s = @"This \r\n is a \r\n\r\n Test. Or, \r\n\r\n\r\n this \r\n.";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

You should write:

```
string s = "This \r\n is a \r\n\r\n Test. Or, \r\n\r\n\r\n this \r\n.";
string n = Regex.Replace(s, "(\r\n)+", "|");
Console.WriteLine(n);
```